# Do not receive a response to some push-requests to the APNs server

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, php-curl

I have about 45000 tokens for which I need to send a push notification.

I send them via `curl_multi_exec` and get roughly 39000 responses from apple.
Majority with status 200 (38650, eg), 300  with status 410 (Unregistered), 50 with status 0 and an empty response body (which is very strange).

But the question remains: where did 6000 requests go?
Maybe these 6000 are 400(BadDeviceToken) or 410(Unregistered)?

Example curl parameters:

```
$curl_option_arr = [
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0, 
    CURLOPT_PORT            => 443,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
      "apns-topic: $apns_topic",
      "authorization: bearer $jwt"
    ],
    CURLOPT_POST            => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => m_json_encode($payload),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 10,
];
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911