# How to update AAACertificateServices on server to send apns?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php, aaacertificateservices

> On March 29, 2021, token and certificate-based HTTP/2 connections to
> the Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root
> certificate (AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020) which replaces the old
> GeoTrust Global CA root certificate. To ensure a seamless transition
> and to avoid push notification delivery failures, verify that both the
> old and new root certificates for the HTTP/2 interface are included in
> the Trust Store of each of your notification servers before March 29.
>
> Note that Apple Push Notification service SSL provider certificates
> issued to you by Apple do not need be to updated at this time.

I got this email regarding the updation of push notification certificates. I am not using any third party service to send apns. I have write PHP script to send notification. previously the same PHP script sent notification but now it's not working. It shows message like **Notification sent successfully** but notification did not deliver. Here is my question about sending notification using PHP Script [APNS not deliver to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323761/apns-not-deliver-to-device).

Please update how to sent notification using php or what to do on server side to manage AAACertificateServices

Thanks

Comment: Found this URL: https://dev.to/samauto/connect-to-apns-via-http-2-with-php-57oj  but it isn't ideal for my current server setup. Anyone have anything else?