# AWS - SNS Endpoint disabled it self for iOS - Apple Device (Failed Push Notification)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, cakephp, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

We are using the AWS SNS for sending the push notification on the Android & iOS applications from the API created on CakePHP platform.

We have created the Application on SNS console as **Development (APNS_SANDBOX)**.

**But the push notification functionality suddenly stop working & sending the below error**

```
Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EndpointDisabled;
```

When we try to enable the Endpoint from the SNS console it **Enabled** for the short time period and it **Disabled** again.

I have written in the code to enable the endpoint if it was disabled.

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo. I've been talking to Apple via support over the weekend. The trick is to send an email late on Friday so there is something to look forward to Monday.

[SendEmptyPushNotification to gateway.push.apple.com no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911)