# Push notification actions not showing if app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm modifying push notifications sent from Apple's push notification service with a **NotificationServiceExtension** in my iOS project. I also set the APNS payload categoryIdentifier inside the extension. In the App's **AppDelegate implementation file** I registered the notification categories with the category that contains my actions. I handle the actions in the **didReceiveNotificationResponse** delegate method.

Everything works fine, except the actions below the extended push notifications are missing when the app is closed. When it's in the fore- or background, the action buttons are displayed.

Is there any way to make them work when the app is completely closed?

Answer (score 0):

Hope all is well. I have been hovering around the APNS tag for the past week or so, relatively speaking.

May I please ask you to verify whether my answer from this question on migrating to the new APNS API is correct?

[SendEmptyPushNotification to gateway.push.apple.com no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911)